# robots.txt file works in localhost but fails on server in php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, robots.txt

I have been developing a web application in Codeigniter - PHP framework, and am creating a dynamic robots.txt for web crawlers, I use a target file robots.txt.php to be accessed dynamically by web crawlers, and the whole operation is successful on localhost.

This is my code in the .htaccess that I use to redirect the static robots.txt file to access the dynamic contents of robots.txt file :

```
RewriteRule ^robots\.txt$ robots.txt.php
```

I Deleted robots.txt file from my localhost, and the robots.txt file works perfectly when I call https://localhost.domain/robots.txt it works but commit my work, and deletion of the file to the server , and i call https://serverdomain/robots.txt
it returns a 404 error, how can I correct it.  I would like to know why it works on the localhost and it does not work on the remote server.

Comment: try like this `RewriteRule ^robots.txt$     /robots.php [L]`

Comment: Does `https://serverdomain/robots.txt.php` work?

Comment: @AD7six I was going to point that, how to add dynamic robots.txt https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86238/can-the-files-robots-txt-and-sitemap-xml-be-dynamic-through-an-htaccess-redirec

Comment: Dilek , let me try that

Comment: @AD7six , https://serverdomain/robots.txt.php   works well on the server when i access it using that url , but when i do https://serverdomain/robots.txt without the .php extension does not work. however , on localhost , all of these  https://serverdomain/robots.txt.php  and https://serverdomain/robots.txt work perfectly

Comment: working locally isn't really relevant - is this the first thing you've used mod rewrite for? I.e. is the problem that _this_ rewrite rule doesn't work, or that _no_ rewrite rules work? What web server are you using remotely?

Comment: @Dilek when i add , RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ /robots.php [L] it does not work , it shows a 404 error

Comment: Remove `.php` extention infront of `.txt` and try to access again if you want to add dynamic `.txt` check refered link. and remove `/` in the codeI gave

Comment: @Dilek removing / does not effect the change too , i have tried it , it is not working yet . i followed the url as referenced in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86238/can-the-files-robots-txt-and-sitemap-xml-be-dynamic-through-an-htaccess-redirec 

Thank you so much for quick feedbacks , but do you have any other fix you think i should try out .

Comment: @wandie no idea, youmust check with your server I think some others can help sorry.